# Cloudera Apache impala query: Memory limit exceeded: Failed to allocate row batch EXCHANGE_NODE?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I run this query and it works :

```
insert into   default.dw_partitioned_table
            partition (partition_islemtarih_string)
select *, cast(replace(strleft(recorddate,10),'-','')as int) as partition_islemtarih_string
from default.dw_hive_table
where recorddate <to_timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
 and  recorddate>=to_timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

But when run 2 different queries at same time , it gives error like below:

```
Memory limit exceeded: Failed to allocate row batch EXCHANGE_NODE (id=1) could not allocate 8.00 KB without exceeding limit. 
Error occurred on backend xxx.xxyy.intra:22000 
Memory left in process limit: 6.54 GB Query(sss:vvv): Reservation=26.20 GB
ReservationLimit=36.72 GB OtherMemory=37.43 MB Total=26.24 GB Peak=26.24 GB 
Fragment sss:vvv: Reservation=25.94 GB OtherMemory=6.60 MB 
Total=25.95 GB Peak=25.95 GB SORT_NODE (id=2): Reservation=25.94 GB 
OtherMemory=40.00 KB Total=25.94 GB Peak=25.94 GB 
EXCHANGE_NODE (id=1): Reservation=6.55 MB
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a very common impala error. This means your sql is consuming huge memory to process the data. You can try braking into parts or you can ask Administrator to allocate more memory to your user.  Also please check out if this statement `cast(replace(strleft(recorddate,10),'-','')as int)` is generating an integer. Pls change it to  `cast(from_timestamp(recorddate,'yyyyMM') as int)` so as to make sure this works.

Comment: thanks for answer , I will try

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of default configurations there are limited guardrails to prevent one query consuming all of the memory on the cluster.

Enabling memory-based admission control for the resource pools in your cluster will prevent this - https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_rm_example.html